# how to get the "next row" and "previous row" in a resultset, without selecting the entire resultset?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

is there a proper way to do this:

```
ID | name
 1 | aa
 4 | bb
 6 | dd
 9 | ee
```

ID is the primary index with auto_increment... missing indexes were DELETEd by SQL so there are some empty spaces

if I navigate in page?ID=4 I want to get the previous row (with ID 1) and the next one (with ID 6) (added:) using the same query

is there a way to do this without selecting/traversing the entire resultset?

thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT * from table where `ID` > 4 ORDER BY `ID` ASC LIMIT 1 /* next */
SELECT * from table where `ID` < 4 ORDER BY `ID` DESC LIMIT 1 /* previous */
```

Comment: thanks! is there a way to do this in the same query? it is because the query is a lot more complex and I don't want to execute it twice, if possible!

Comment: These require `ORDER BY id ASC` and `ORDER BY id DESC` clauses to guarantee which record is returned.

Comment: @toPeerOrNotToPeer you can use UNION

Comment: thank you everybody for the answers and comments! i want to accept all of them but i can not! :(

Comment: @toPeerOrNotToPeer accepting answer gives 15+ repo and upvote +10. So you can appericiate others answer by upvoting them and as i guess you have done that so there are no worries for selecting one answer only.

Answer (score 3):

I would do something like this (for previous record):

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE id < @id
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 1
```

That should be enough info for the DB engine to optimize the query.

Comment: thanks! what about selecting both next and previous in the same query?

Comment: UNION two queries together to get both, and include a string like 'next' and 'prev' to differentiate them.

Comment: @toPeerOrNotToPeer i don't think there is any problem of union in your case.

Comment: @toPeerOrNotToPeer I don't think you have any performance worries there.  Id is probably a clustered index, right?  Selecting a single row of a clustered index is about the fastest query that exists.

Answer (score 2):

Give it a try-

```
(SELECT * FROM table_name
WHERE id < 4
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 1)
union 
(SELECT * FROM table_name
WHERE id > 4
ORDER BY id ASC
LIMIT 1)
```